# AttributeError: PyStreamCallback object has no attribute length

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read flowfile content which is JSON file,  count length of this JSON array of elements and then write it to a new attribute.

But somehow I always get aforementioned error. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you beforehand!

Here's my script

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
import json


class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    jsn = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    array = json.loads(jsn) # type: dict
    i = 0
    while i <= 1:
      root_key = list(array.keys())[0]
      array = array[root_key]
      i += 1
    self.length = str(len(array))

  def get_length_of_array(self):
    return self.length

# end class
flowfile = session.get()
if(flowfile != None):
    flowfile = session.write(flowfile, PyStreamCallback())
    flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, "length", PyStreamCallback().get_length_of_array())
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: What exactly the error message you have?

Comment: You are creating `PyStreamCallback()` object 2 times. For the second instance the length attribute is not defined yet.

Comment: @daggett this is exactly what error message says  
AttributeError: PyStreamCallback object has no attribute length

Can you please point me where I create it second time?

Comment: jest search for exactly this string  in your code `PyStreamCallback()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating PyStreamCallback() object 2 times. For the second instance the length attribute is not defined yet.

it should be like this:

```py
# end class
flowfile = session.get()
if(flowfile != None):
    callback = PyStreamCallback()
    flowfile = session.write(flowfile, callback)
    flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, "length", callback.get_length_of_array())
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```